# Is it possible to create a remote mongodb replica set member for a mongodb atlas cluster?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-replica-set

I have an atlas cluster database and a remote ubuntu server with mongodb. I want to add the remote db as a replicaset member of my cluster database.

I have tried to add a new member using the command `rs.add()` but I got a unauthorized permission error.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The main problem is, you don't have access to the keyfile which is used (and required) for [internal membership authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/)

Comment: No it's not possible. You might be able to use the [mongosync tool](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/cluster-to-cluster-sync/current/reference/mongosync/) to keep the data on the two places the same though

Answer (score 0):

it means that the user you are using to authenticate does not have the necessary permissions to perform this operation.

To add a new replica set member to your Atlas cluster, you need to use a user with the following roles:"clusterAdmin" or "atlasAdmin" role for clusters created before November 13, 2020
"Atlas admin" role for clusters created after November 13, 2020

Comment: The user have the "atlasAdmin" role. But I am using a free cluster. Is there any limitations for adding a replica member from a free cluster ?